# Disk space used by iPhoto/iMovie libraries on OS X

Tags: macos, photos.app, imovie, storage

How can I tell how much space my iphotos and imovies are taking on my Macbook Pro hard drive? I've checked the applications from my finder, but iphoto and imovie are not listed there.

Answer (score 2):

- iPhoto pictures are stored in `~/Pictures/iPhoto Library`
- iMovie movies are stored in `~/Movies/iMovie Events` (iMovie 9) or `~/Movies/iMovie Library` (iMovie 10, name may be different as my system runs on German settings)

Select the library and type <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> to open the "Get Info" window which also shows file size (may take a while to calculate).